# Blog matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am using slug to to show my blog details page.

here is models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='post_author')
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=264,verbose_name='Put a Title')
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    blog_content=models.TextField(verbose_name='what is on your mind?')
    blog_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images',verbose_name='Image')
    publish_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish_date',)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title+'  From :'+str(self.author)
```

blog list views.py

```
def Creating_blog(request):
    form=BlogForm()
    if User.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=='POST':
                form=BlogForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                blog_obj=form.save(commit=False)
                blog_obj.author=request.user
                title=blog_obj.blog_title
                blog_obj.slug = title.replace(' ','-') + '-'+ str(uuid.uuid4())
                blog_obj.save()
                return redirect('bloglist')
    return render(request,'blogs/createblog.html',{'form':form})
```

blog details views.py

```
def blog_details(request, slug):
    if User.is_authenticated:
        blog= Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
        already_liked=Likes.objects.filter(blog=blog,user=request.user)
        if already_liked:
            like=True
        else:
            like=False
        comments=Comment.objects.filter(blog=blog)
        commet_form=CommentForm()
        if request.method=='POST':
          commet_form=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if commet_form.is_valid():
            comment=commet_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user=request.user
            comment.blog=blog
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_details',kwargs={'slug':slug}))
        return render(request,'blogs/blogdetails.html',context={'blog':blog,'comment_form':commet_form,'comments':comments,'like':like})
    else:
        HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('write/',views.Creating_blog,name='creatingblogs'),
    path('bloglist/',views.BlogList.as_view(),name='bloglist'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>/',views.blog_details,name="blog_details")
]
```

blog_list page html anchor tag code

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>{{blog.blog_content|capfirst|truncatewords:100}}<a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug|slugify %}">Read More</a></p>
    </div>
```

I can see the blog list page but when it try to see blog details it shows me this error

```
DoesNotExist at /details/big-time-space-rarity-9a3d63b4-634a-11ec-9db9-9c7bef6a0e62/
Blog matching query does not exist.
```

I have tried adding some new blog but it shows me the same. please help me out this and kindly ask me if any description needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `views.blog_details` in `urs.py`? Could you share the code of this view?

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev  to show blog details page code.  This is not taking me to the blog details page, that's the problem.

Comment: I totally understood your question :) By the way, could you share with us the code of this view `views.blog_details` to make sure it's not the problem?

Comment: Please show us your detail view. I'm pretty sure the problem is there. As you are passing the slug of your blog, you basically have to tell the detail view to search the respective blog by the slug (django uses pk by default). Other than that I strongly recommend class based views. You probably don't need the slugify tag in your template and check out the slugify functon to create your slug initially.

Comment: @R.Steigmeier I got you but I am familiar with function based view that's why. I am putting blog details view

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev I have edited the post. If you have any blog projects done using slug you can give the the source. That would be very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs inside the `blog_details` view in the row:

```
blog= Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

You should debug this part of the code and determine why you can't find the `Blog` instance by slug.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a wild guess as I'm not reproducing your code but in my opinion something with your slug seems wrong.

First change the following line:

```
blog_obj.slug = slugify(title + '-' + str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

then change the following:

```
<p>{{blog.blog_content|capfirst|truncatewords:100}}<a href="{% url 'blog_details' slug=blog.slug %}">Read More</a></p>
```

(remove slugify in the template)

Let me know if this worked. Also, if you need help with class based views, just let us know.